# How to remove vehicles from an aerial photograph

Tags: envi, erdas-imagine

I have an aerial photograph of an area. The image includes visible traffic signs and vehicles. How can I remove the vehicles from the image? Is it possible to do so in software like Erdas or Envi using methods like Density Slicing? If possible, please tell me the procedure.

Comment: photoshop can do this with manual intervention. here is an example of removal - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7FnhOzbvSc

Comment: I few questions for you to help focus your question:  What type of imagery?  Resolution? How many spectral bands?  What else exists in the image (vegetation, buildings, etc)?  Could you post a sample image?

Comment: Photoshop can do this, its easy also. But i want the georeferenced image. Also the image is about 12 gb size, It cant be directly used in photoshop. It is an RGB image. When used in photoshope, the georeferencing is lost.

Answer (score 4):

you can try doing object based classification based on size and signatures of the vehicles and look at the results. Then you can remove vehicles from the image. Afaik, there is nothing that will do it in one click.

Answer (score -1):

You should have started searching web first. Here you are a [sufficient collection of techniques](http://scholar.google.ru/scholar?q=gis%20vehicle%20detection%20space%20imagery&btnG=&hl=ru&as_sdt=0) that have been used for fulfilling such tasks. Nothing can be advised more precisely because we don't know parameters of your imagery.

**Edit:**
Don't know why my answer is so unwelcome. Recently I was concerned with vehicle detection myself and these scientific articles gave me some clue. One still have to detect vehicles before removing.

Comment: speculating here, you didn't provide a direct answer with methodology options. I thought the idea here was not to point to Google searches, rather provide adequate solutions to the questions regardless how simple they might seem

Comment: @dassouki, yes seems that it is how it looks like. But it is the wrong impression. I have read 5 articles from that search query and would point to one of them instead of the whole query, but as I wrote the information about the data used by topicstarter is missing and articles are targeting different data sources.

Comment: perhaps link to each article separately and provided a small summary?

Comment: @dassouki, you really suggest me to spend another hour writing essay just because the insufficient information was given in the question? Maybe someday (for I really do such things)... For now I think I'll just watch the source of information being down-voted and will wait for someone who will provide some 'simple' solution for this really 'simple' problem.

Comment: The patronizing tone ("you should have started searching web first") combined with a single link to Google results are probably reasons for the downvotes.

Comment: @GeoKevin, seems that no one consider reading "how to ask" section... http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask